# How to install and use Slim template engine with Middleman

Tags: ruby, slim-lang, middleman

I'm new to Middleman and ruby in general.

I've installed Ruby
I've installed Middleman and the gems to get it running.

I need to use slim instead of the default template system.

So I installed the Slim gem. Slim's website only says that I need to require 'slim' in order to get it to work.

The middleman website says I only need add the template engine to the config.rb file, but it gives no examples...

For someone with no ruby background, this is no help.

I looked for several config.rb on git and they all have:

```
require 'slim'
```

And

```
# Set slim-lang output style
Slim::Engine.set_default_options :pretty => true

# Set template languages
set :slim, :layout_engine => :slim
```

I added that to my config.rb file and created the layout.slim and the index.html.slim

When I refresh my local server I get:

```
Not Found

`/' not found.
```

I have middleman installed with Boilerplace. I'm not sure if there are more files that I need to change, but I can't find any good resources online, which is odd.

Could anyone give me some direction as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get Slim working with Middleman

1. Add `gem "slim"` to your project's gemfile
2. go to command line, in your project folder and `gem install bundler`
3. In the config.rb file add `require 'slim'`
4. Start the middleman server to test it

Answer (score 1):

The [middleman-slim](https://github.com/yterajima/middleman-slim) project by [yterajima](https://github.com/yterajima) is helpful in this regard.

Install is very easy.

```
$ gem install middleman
$ gem install middleman-slim
$ middleman init PROJECT_NAME --template slim
```

Comment: In middleman 4 it will be as `middleman init MY_PROJECT -T yterajima/middleman-slim`

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, it appears necessary to avoid Slim 5.x.

Middleman should support Slim templates simply by adding `gem 'slim'` to your Gemfile, however, this installed Slim 5.1.0 and produced errors when I tried to load the simplest possible `index.html.slim`, containing simply `h1 test`.

To fix this, I replace `gem 'slim'` with `gem 'slim', '~>4.0'` and rand `bundle install`. This downgraded Slim to 4.1.0, which is now working fine.