# Include a slim file in another slim file

Tags: ruby, slim-lang, static-html

I'm working on a static website (so no real server support) and I would like to include a small slim snippet in another, possibly passing a variable to it.

Is this possible? In rails is quite easy, though the `render` method, but I have no idea how to do it on slim (obviously `load` method doesn't work for slim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can be done in this way:

```
Slim::Template.new('template.slim', optional_option_hash).render(scope)
```

Found in slim readme: https://github.com/slim-template/slim

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this answer? I am trying to do the same. Let's say the name of the file is index.slim and I want to include the partial _variables.slim in it. Thanks!

Comment: Well just type in your slim file `Slim::Template.new('_variables.slim', optional_option_hash).render(scope)` there isn't a lot more I can say about it, the "partial" thing is only available in Rails, not in Slim only. If you are using Rails you just need `render 'variables'`

Comment: Thanks. Too bad it works only in Rails. I was using Codekit to compile Slim templates into static html, but without that capability it's useless. I'll use Jade.

Comment: You can easily emulate partial capabilities in slim with the Slim::Template code.

Answer (score 7):

Slim contains `Include` plugin that allows to include other files directly in template files at compile time:

```
require 'slim/include'

include partial_name
```

Documentations is available here: https://github.com/slim-template/slim/blob/master/doc/include.md

If you need to include the files at runtime

`Slim::Template.new("#{ name }.slim").render` does the job (https://github.com/slim-template/slim#include-helper).

Comment: Hm, I didn't have to add that "require". Maybe, that's because rails does it automatically for me

Answer (score 2):

I would **strongly** reocommend checking out [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) if you want to build a static website using Slim. Middleman borrows common helper functions like `render` and `partial` from Padrino, a web framework sort of like Rails but built using the more lightweight Sinatra (all of these are great software).

The poins is that you can configure Middleman to use slim and then nest partials (or layouts as well) arbitrarily. If you run into snags, check [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626845/how-to-install-and-use-slim-template-engine-with-middleman). It's pretty simple though!

The Middleman docs explain how to use partials [here](http://middlemanapp.com/basics/templates/#partials), and you can see how a real-world example looks in [my gist for embedding an HTML5 video player](https://gist.github.com/SteveBenner/9029034).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems interesting, I ended up using Grunt for the moment and angularjs, removing the requirement for `render` and `partial`. Still, for websites without angular, this is great, I'm checking it right now.

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me write a really killer partials helper that gives you Rails-like partials functionality. I'm really pleased with it!

```
#partials_helper.rb
module PartialsHelper
  def partial(name, path: '/partials', locals: {})
    Slim::Template.new("#{settings.views}#{path}/#{name}.slim").render(self, locals)
  end
end
```

-

```
#app.rb
require 'slim'
require 'slim/include'
require 'partials_helper'
require 'other_helper_methods'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  helpers do
    include PartialsHelper
    include OtherHelperMethods
  end

  get '/' do
    slim :home
  end
end
```

-

```
#views/home.slim
== partial :_hello_world, locals: { name: 'Andrew' }
```

-

```
#views/partials/_hello_world.slim
h1 Hello, World! Hello #{name}!
```

I initially had only `.render({}, locals)`, which meant that the partials didn't have access to any helper methods contained inside `OtherHelperMethods` (but `home.slim` did). Passing `self` into `.render`, as the first argument, fixes that (if you're curious about that, look up the `Tilt::Template #render` documentation.

With this PartialsHelper, passing locals is optional, as is specifying a different path to the partial (relative to `settings.views`).

Hope you get as much use out of it as I do!

Comment: The entire purpose was to use slim for a *static website*, you are running the helper in sinatra though, that's dynamic :P